# PHP code not interpreted in AJAX request with Google App Engin PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use AJAX request on Google App Engine.
In my development environment, all is OK, my request is correctly interpreted. But when I update my code in production, the render of AJAX request is the code in my php file (json expected). It as if the code was interpreted as flat text , not like php.
Here my scripts :

App.yaml file :

```
application: app-name
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /web/css
  static_dir: web/css

- url: /web/js
  static_dir: web/js

- url: /web/img
  static_dir: web/img

- url: /web/fonts
  static_dir: web/fonts

- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /add/update
  script: /service/formService.php

- url: /delete
  script: /service/deleteFormService.php

- url: /ajax/init
  script: web/js/ajax/init.php

- url: /ajax/suiviEtudes
  script: web/js/ajax/suiviEtudes.php

- url: /ajax/refreshProjectsPosition
  script: web/js/ajax/refreshProjectsPosition.php
```

Javascript file :

```
function initProjects(){
    $.ajax({ url: 'web/js/ajax/init.php',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            alert(output);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest.status);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

My php file :

```
<?php

require_once('../../../dao/dao.php');
include('../../../service/baseService.php');
include('../../../service/TownEPCIService.php');
include('../../../service/ContextService.php');
include('../../../service/LinkService.php');

$objProject = new project();
$baseService = new baseService();
$contextService = new contextService();
$linkService = new LinkService();
$townEPCIService = new TownEPCIService();

$project = $objProject->getAll();

$towns = $townEPCIService->getTownsByProjects($project);
$urbanismRules = $baseService->getUrbanismRule();
$ficabilityTypes = $baseService->getFiscabilityType();
$deliberations = $townEPCIService->getDeliberations();
$epcis = $townEPCIService->getEpciByProjects($project);
$studies = $baseService->getStudiesByProject($project);
$themes = $baseService->getThemes();
$states = $baseService->getStatesLabels();
$siteCaracteristics = $contextService->getCaracSiteByProject($project);
$indicators = $baseService->getIndicators();
$consultations = $contextService->getConsultationsByProject($project);

echo json_encode(['projets' => $project,
    'towns' => $towns,
    'urbanismRules' => $urbanismRules,
    'ficabilityTypes' => $ficabilityTypes,
    'deliberations' => $deliberations,
    'epcis' => $epcis,
    'etudes' => $studies,
    'themes' => $themes,
    'states' => $states,
    'siteCaracteristics' => $siteCaracteristics,
    'indicators' => $indicators,
    'consultations' => $consultations]);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax is posting to /web/js/..., which is explicitly defined as a static route in your app.yaml; static routes by definition serve static content, not interpreted scripts.

You do have a route defined for /ajax/init, you probably need to post to that instead. However, your PHP files themselves should *not* live under the static js directory.

Comment: Effectively, my problem was the location of my php file. It was under a static route. I tried to change it location and now it work perfectly ! I really thank you Daniel

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear, in production your php code is not interpreted?
If answer is yes you need check server configuration if the module php is enabled.